# TwiML for Connecting an Outbound Call?

Tags: twilio, twilio-twiml

I'm attempting to create a TwiML app, but the documentation is a little overwhelming for my simple use-case.

Outbound calls from soft phone are bridged with another call:

1. Call made from FromDID (from VoIP client) to ToDID (ie. +11111111111)
2. Twilio first calls another DID (ie. +12222222222)
3. On answer, connects call with ToDID
4. On no answer, drops call

This allows me to trigger calls from my VoIP client, but my goal is to simply use my VoIP client to trigger a bridge between my mobile DID and whatever DID I'm attempting to call (so that I'm using cellular networks for my calls rather than data).

The current TwiML app simply makes the call to a destination DID. Any advice or tutorials I can follow for this use-case?

```xml
<Response>
    <Dial answerOnBridge="true" callerId="{{#e164}}{{From}}{{/e164}}">{{#e164}}{{To}}{{/e164}}</Dial>
</Response>
```

Comment: It’s not clear what you are trying to achieve. If your Softphone kicks off and the call, what happens to it once the other calls are connected? What are you trying for I achieve at a higher level?

Comment: @alan I have a Twilio number and my personal mobile number (i.e. Verizon). I'd like to be able to trigger an outbound call from Zoiper (softphone) which calls my mobile first to connect me to the destination. This would be useful because I live in an area with low data bandwidth, so VoIP calls that require a data connection often get dropped. If I can bridge to my mobile, but the destination receives the call from my Twilio number, it would allow me to use the cell network to make calls from my Twilio number.

Ideally, I'd love to set this up in Twilio Studio instead of a TwiML app, too.

Comment: It sounds like you are using the Zoiper Softphone as a trigger to set-up two unrelated calls and this allows you to use your Twilio number as your callerId. You could use an HTTP endpoint trigger to a Studio Flow or a Twilio Function to do the same. Would that work better for you rather then having to use your Softphone to trigger this?

Comment: That's the configuration we had before, but this doesn't make many of the softphone features available, such as a contact list, turning phone numbers into links to trigger calls, inbound call handling, etc. In that case, the rep has to know the number of the person they are calling in order to provide it as a param to the webhook. We're going for ease of use for non-technical users and don't want to build our own client.
Is there no way to accomplish it with a softphone?

Comment: Got it. Yes it is possible. You will need to have the SIP Softphone inbound call trigger the SIP Domain Voice URL to execute the logic. The logic can be hosted on as Twilio Function which makes a call to the /Calls Resource to trigger an outbound call to your mobile number and once answered it executes the TwiML you pass into to the number you dialed via your SIP client (you need to pull of the E.164 portion of that number since Twilio will provide the number + your SIP Domain. There is some basic code here: https://www.twilio.com/docs/runtime/quickstart/make-a-call

Comment: This blog has some code to show you how to extract just the E.164 portion of the inbound SIP call: https://www.twilio.com/blog/registering-sip-phone-twilio-inbound-outbound